# Keeping the specified color for JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am having this Layout in `JTabeedPane` with the background as shown. The background color is not changing to the color as shown. I am the following structure while designing.

```
JFrame (Background color: [0,115,153])
 JPanel (Background color: [3,50,67])
  JPanel (Background color: [16,110,173])
   ...
  JPanel  (Background color: [3,50,67])
   JTabbedPane  (Background color: [3,50,67])
    Tab 1,2,3   (Background color: [3,50,67])
```

The white color isn't enabled in any of the Foreground or Background colors but it's still visible there. I tested it while keeping the components **Opaque** and disabling **Opaque** but no effect. How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can easier understand your problem and provide a solution, that is suitable for your case. Please don't post your complete code, but rather create a small runnable class, that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Okay.Lemme separate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not as trivial as one might expect because this formatting is completely managed by the Look and Feel.

However you can call `tabbedPane.setUI(yourCustomUI);` to set a custom UI.

I have prepared a UI for you to use, hope it safes you some time (see inline-comments to customize):

```
// your code...

tabbedPane.setUI(new MinimalisticTabbedPaneUI());

// your code...

public static class MinimalisticTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {

    // paints the border around the currently visible content
    @Override
    protected void paintContentBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {
        // do nothing
    }

    // paints the border around each tab
    @Override
    protected void paintTabBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
        // only paints a border if the tab is selected, edit this to add your personal formatting
        if(isSelected){
            super.paintTabBorder(g, tabPlacement, tabIndex, x, y, w, h, isSelected);
        }
    }
}
```